# Поля ввода появляются не там, где надо

Tags: python, json, tkinter

Делал на **tkinter** окно авторизации с проверкой данных из **json** файла. Проверка проходит успешно, но с окном что-то не так.

Есть окно с одной кнопкой "Авторизация", при нажатии на неё, происходит проверка на данные из **json** файла. В файле две переменные, `token`, `group_id`.

Проверка на данные:

```
with open("account.json", "r") as readFile:
                read = json.load(readFile)

if read['token'] == None:
        if read['group_id'] == None:
```

Если данные значения пусты, то происходит следующие. Открывается другое окно, как раз для того, чтобы ввести все нужные данные:

```
if read['token'] == None:
        if read['group_id'] == None:

                from tkinter import messagebox

                #messagebox.showwarning('Ошибка авторизации', 'Программа не смогла установить ваши данные, введите их пожалуйста в поле данных, для дальнейших действий.')

                root.geometry('400x150')
                root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
                root.title('Авторизация > Ввод данных')
                root.iconbitmap(r'iconAuth.ico')

                token = StringVar()
                groupID = StringVar()

                tokenLabel = Label(text="Введите токен группы:")
                groupIDLabel = Label(text="Введите ID группы:")

                tokenLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")
                groupIDLabel.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="w")

                tokenEntry = Entry(textvariable=token)
                groupIDEntry = Entry(textvariable=groupID)

                tokenEntry.grid(row=0,column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
                groupIDEntry.grid(row=1,column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

                message_button = Button(text="Авторизация", command=functionButtonWrite)
                message_button.grid(row=2,column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="e")

                root.mainloop()



        '''with open("account.json", "r") as authFile:
                data = json.load(authFile)

        vk_session = VkApi(token=data['token'])
        longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, data['group_id'])
        vk = vk_session.get_api()'''

    root.mainloop()
```

Но происходит следующие. Вместо того, чтобы всё это ^^^^ (Код), появилось в этом окне, он появляется в самом главном окне:

[image: ...]

Что делать, не знаю. Прошу помочь. 
Вот полный код:

```
import vk_api
from vk_api import VkApi
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import *
from vk_api.longpoll import *
from tkinter import *
import os 
import json
from random import *

# MAIN
root = Tk()

# GUI
root.geometry("400x500")
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
root.configure(background='#2a5885')
#root.iconbitmap(r'iconVkClient.ico')
#root.title('< VkClient >')

for i in range(20):

        import random

        x = random.random()

        if x <= 0.2:
                root.title('< ВкКлиент >')
                root.iconbitmap(r'smile.ico')
        else:
                root.title('< VkClient >')
                root.iconbitmap(r'iconVkClient.ico')

# FUNCTION'S
def functionButtonExit():

        root = Tk()
        text = Text(root)
        root.geometry('300x90')
        root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        root.title('Завершение программы')
        root.iconbitmap(r'cancel.ico')

        textExit = Label(root, text='Завершить программу?').pack()
        buttonConfirmExit = Button(root, text='Да', padx=5, pady=2, command=ExitVkClient).place(x=50, y=30)
        buttonDenyExit = Button(root, text='Нет', padx=5, pady=2,  command=root.destroy).place(x=200, y=30)

        root.mainloop()

def functionButtonInformation():

        root = Tk()
        root.geometry('400x500')
        root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        root.title('Информация')
        root.iconbitmap(r'iconInf.ico')

        textFile = '\nИнформация о < VkClient >\n\n\n\n\n\nКлиент был разработан на языке программирования Python,\nразработан для лёгкого использования VKAPI, так и для создания бота.\nОткрытый код, Вы можете найти по ссылке ниже.\n\n\n\nСоздатель: hoojpop\n\nСвязь:\n\nVK: https://vk.com/hoojpop\nEmail: hoojpop@inbox.ru\nОткрытый код:'

        textInf = Label(root, text=textFile).pack()

        buttonExitInformation = Button(root, text='> Закрыть <', padx='10', pady='5', font='4', activeforeground='#FFFFFF', activebackground='#008080', command=root.destroy).place(x=140, y=450)

        root.mainloop()

def functionButtonAuth():

        root = Tk()
        root.geometry('400x500')
        root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        root.title('Авторизация')
        root.iconbitmap(r'iconAuth.ico')

        with open("account.json", "r") as readFile:
                read = json.load(readFile)

        if read['token'] == None:
                if read['group_id'] == None:


                        from tkinter import messagebox

                        #messagebox.showwarning('Ошибка авторизации', 'Программа не смогла установить ваши данные, введите их пожалуйста в поле данных, для дальнейших действий.')

                        root.geometry('400x150')
                        root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
                        root.title('Авторизация > Ввод данных')
                        root.iconbitmap(r'iconAuth.ico')

                        token = StringVar()
                        groupID = StringVar()

                        tokenLabel = Label(text="Введите токен группы:")
                        groupIDLabel = Label(text="Введите ID группы:")

                        tokenLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")
                        groupIDLabel.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="w")

                        tokenEntry = Entry(textvariable=token)
                        groupIDEntry = Entry(textvariable=groupID)

                        tokenEntry.grid(row=0,column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
                        groupIDEntry.grid(row=1,column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

                        message_button = Button(text="Авторизация", command=functionButtonWrite)
                        message_button.grid(row=2,column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="e")

                        root.mainloop()



                '''with open("account.json", "r") as authFile:
                        data = json.load(authFile)

                vk_session = VkApi(token=data['token'])
                longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, data['group_id'])
                vk = vk_session.get_api()'''
                root.mainloop()

def functionButtonWrite():

        from tkinter import messagebox

        print()

def ExitVkClient():

        sys.exit()

buttonAuth = Button(text='> Авторизация <', padx='20', pady='5', font='10', activeforeground='#FFFFFF', activebackground='#008080', command=functionButtonAuth).place(x=111, y=180)
buttonExit = Button(text='> Завершить программу <', padx='10', pady='5', font='5', command=functionButtonExit, activeforeground='#FFFFFF', activebackground='#008080').place(x=88, y=450)
buttonInformation = Button(text='> Информация <', padx='10', pady='5', font='5', command=functionButtonInformation, activeforeground='#FFFFFF', activebackground='#008080').place(x=120, y=223)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если при создании виджета не указан родительский объект, то виджет крепится к главному окну. Обратите внимание на подобные строки внутри функции `functionButtonAuth`:

```
tokenEntry = Entry(textvariable=token)
```

В исправленном виде функция будет выглядеть примерно так (уменьшил отступы, чтобы были видны комментарии с пометками):

```
def functionButtonAuth():
    auth_window = Toplevel()
    auth_window.geometry('400x500')
    auth_window.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    auth_window.title('Авторизация')
    auth_window.iconbitmap(r'iconAuth.ico')

    with open("account.json", "r") as readFile:
        read = json.load(readFile)

    if read['token'] == None:
        if read['group_id'] == None:
            from tkinter import messagebox

            #messagebox.showwarning('Ошибка авторизации', 'Программа не смогла установить ваши данные, введите их пожалуйста в поле данных, для дальнейших действий.')

            auth_window.geometry('400x150')
            auth_window.resizable(width=False, height=False)
            auth_window.title('Авторизация > Ввод данных')
            auth_window.iconbitmap(r'iconAuth.ico')

            token = StringVar()
            groupID = StringVar()

            tokenLabel = Label(auth_window, text="Введите токен группы:")  # <<<<
            groupIDLabel = Label(auth_window, text="Введите ID группы:")  # <<<<

            tokenLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")
            groupIDLabel.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="w")

            tokenEntry = Entry(auth_window, textvariable=token)  # <<<<
            groupIDEntry = Entry(auth_window, textvariable=groupID)  # <<<<

            tokenEntry.grid(row=0,column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
            groupIDEntry.grid(row=1,column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

            message_button = Button(auth_window, text="Авторизация", command=functionButtonWrite)  # <<<<
            message_button.grid(row=2,column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="e")
```

Также, обратите внимание, что дочерние окна должны создаваться не как объекты `Tk`, а как объекты класса `Toplevel`. В вашем коде во всех функциях нужно заменить `Tk` на `Toplevel` и убрать вызовы `mainloop` (внутри этих функций). В итоге должен остаться только один вызов `root = Tk()` в самом верху и только один `root.mainloop()` в самом внизу. Если это не сделать, то могут не работать переменные привязанные к виджетам.

Пример исправления:

```
def functionButtonExit():

        root = Toplevel()  # <-- Toplevel вместо Tk
        text = Text(root)
        root.geometry('300x90')
        root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        root.title('Завершение программы')
        root.iconbitmap(r'cancel.ico')

        textExit = Label(root, text='Завершить программу?').pack()
        buttonConfirmExit = Button(root, text='Да', padx=5, pady=2, command=ExitVkClient).place(x=50, y=30)
        buttonDenyExit = Button(root, text='Нет', padx=5, pady=2,  command=root.destroy).place(x=200, y=30)

        # root.mainloop()  # <-- убрать
```

Также я бы переименовал переменные `root` внутри функций на что-то другое (как я сделал в первом фрагменте кода), чтобы не путать с главным окном.

Comment: А, вон оно что. Понял. Сейчас попробую.